# What is difference between Static Constructor assignment and Inline-initialize syntax

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I want to know what is exactly the benefit of `Static Constructor`?

In my case, I have a class `Test` with a static member called `Id`.

I can set the value to `Id` as inline syntax:

```
public class Test
{
    public static int Id = 10;
}
```

anyway. some article says the static constructor is used for conditional value setting to static members...

So I create a class called `Test1` with static member `ChildId` and `ChildId` pend for `Id` value inside the `Test` class.

As you can see I can conditional value setting as inline syntax:

```
class Test1
{
    public static int ChildId = Test.Id < 10 ? 20 : 100;
}
```

what is exactly the benefit of `Static Constructor`?

Comment: Well, not all initialisation can be done in a single expression.

Comment: Can you give an example? @Sweeper

Comment: @Sajad Kardel: Imagine, that you want to get `ChildId` from *database* - you need some code, not just an assignment.

Comment: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) is always a good place to start....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here:

1. the *order* of field initializers can make code brittle if field initializers interact with other fields; the order is top-to-bottom, which means:

   - moving code around can break things
   - when using `partial` types over multiple files, the order is essentially non-deterministic, making field initializers that rely on fields in other files very unwise
2. sometimes you need multiple steps to initialize a field, involving temporary variables etc; not everything can be achieved in the single expression allowed by a field initializer (a `static` method is also a viable option here, if you want multiple steps without triggering `beforefieldinit`)
3. static initializers also trigger an IL behavior called `beforefieldinit`; whether you want this (or even care about this) is contextual, and it is complicated; [useful reference](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/BeforeFieldInit)